# How can I build an Actionscript3.0 mobile project with air sdk command lines?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got an Actionscript3.0 mobile project in Flash Builder and I want to build it into an swf file with air sdk 4.0 command lines. Any help?

***update***

I have got an answer to the question.(Reference given by jauboux)

1. dump a config file using compiler argument `-dump-config=C:\a.xml`.
2. mxmlc project with the config file, generating an swf file.

   `mxmlc Entry.as -load-config C:\a.xml`
3. adt swf to ipa.

   `adt -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -provision-file a.mobileprovision 
    -storetype pkcs12 -keystore a.p12 -storepass passwordhere 
    a.ipa a-app.xml a.swf
    embedpath1 embedpath2
    -extdir ane`

*PS Thank VC.One for pointing out the problem of my question.*

Comment: You got downvoted (not me) cos around here they hate lack of effort. At least say what mobile OS and what commands you have tried to use. Anyway hope this link helps.. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Hello World example from Adobe for [Android](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html) and [iOS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f3cb56e2a12cc36970aa-8000.html) giving you all the necessary steps